# Sql Server CRUD LOGGER in all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, triggers, crud

A- I need to create a CRUD logger, and its working as well with folowing script, but the problem is that the script does in only one table...

**Objective: Install de trigger above in ALL tables, not in ONE TABLE.
I tried to put script 1 into script 2 but no sucess, with so much concatening errors.**

**Script 1 (its working but in only a table):**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.audit_trigger; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.audit_trigger (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Type CHAR(1),
    TableName VARCHAR(128),
    PK VARCHAR(1000),
    FieldName VARCHAR(128),
    OldValue VARCHAR(1000),
    NewValue VARCHAR(1000),
    UpdateDate datetime,
    UserName VARCHAR(128)
);
GO





--deletar trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dbo.tr_UserRole;
GO


CREATE TRIGGER tr_UserRole ON UserRole
    FOR  
        INSERT, 
        UPDATE, 
        DELETE 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
/*declare all the variables*/
DECLARE @bit INT;
DECLARE @field INT;
DECLARE @maxfield INT;
DECLARE @char INT;
DECLARE @fieldname VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @PKCols VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21);
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @Type CHAR(1);
DECLARE @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000);

/*now set some of these variables*/
SET @TableName = (
    SELECT 
        OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE 
        sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
);
SET @UserName = SYSTEM_USER;
SET @UpdateDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126);

INSERT INTO audit_trigger (    
                Type, 
                TableName, 
                PK, 
                FieldName, 
                OldValue, 
                NewValue, 
                UpdateDate, 
                UserName
            ) values ( '', '','','','','', @UpdateDate ,''   );

/*Action*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
         SET @Type = 'U'
    ELSE SET @Type = 'I'
    ELSE SET @Type = 'D'
;
/*get list of columns*/
SELECT * 
INTO #ins
FROM INSERTED;

SELECT * 
INTO #del
FROM DELETED;

/*set @PKCols and @PKSelect via SELECT statement.*/
SELECT @PKCols = /*Get primary key columns for full outer join*/
        COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
        + ' i.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = d.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS pk
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS c ON (
            c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
            AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        )
    WHERE pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
;
SELECT @PKSelect = /*Get primary key select for insert*/
        COALESCE(@PKSelect + '+', '') 
        + '''<[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']=''+convert(varchar(100),
        coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))+''>'''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
    WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
;
IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName);
    RETURN;
END

SET @field = 0;
SET @maxfield = (
    SELECT 
        MAX(
            COLUMNPROPERTY(
                OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                COLUMN_NAME,
                'ColumnID'
            )
        )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE  
        TABLE_NAME = @TableName
);

WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
    SET @field = (
        SELECT 
            MIN(
                COLUMNPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                    COLUMN_NAME,
                    'ColumnID'
                )
            )
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE  
            TABLE_NAME = @TableName
            AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                    COLUMN_NAME,
                    'ColumnID'
                ) > @field
    );
    SET @bit = (@field - 1)% 8 + 1;
    SET @bit = POWER(2, @bit - 1);
    SET @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1;

    IF (
        SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(), @char, 1) & @bit > 0
        OR @Type IN ('I', 'D')
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @fieldname = (
            SELECT 
                COLUMN_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE  
                TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                        COLUMN_NAME,
                        'ColumnID'
                    ) = @field
        );
        SET @sql = ('

                       

            INSERT INTO audit_trigger (    
                Type, 
                TableName, 
                PK, 
                FieldName, 
                OldValue, 
                NewValue, 
                UpdateDate, 
                UserName
            )
            SELECT ''' 
                + @Type + ''',''' 
                + @TableName + ''',' 
                + @PKSelect + ',''' 
                + @fieldname + ''''
                + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
                + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
                + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
                + ',''' + @UserName + '''' + 
            ' FROM #ins AS i FULL OUTER JOIN #del AS d'
                    + @PKCols + 
            ' WHERE i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
                    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                    + @fieldname
                    + ' is not null)' 
                    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                    + @fieldname
                    + ' is null)' 
        );
        EXEC (@sql)
    END
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

**Script 2:**

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE cur_trigger CURSOR FOR
    SELECT      '
CREATE TRIGGER [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[tr' + TABLE_NAME + '_aeae]
ON [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
 script 1 goes here...................................

   
END

CLOSE cur_trigger
DEALLOCATE cur_trigger
```

**My try:**

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE cur_trigger CURSOR FOR
    SELECT      '
CREATE TRIGGER [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[tr' + TABLE_NAME + '_aeae]
ON [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
/*declare all the variables*/
DECLARE @bit INT;
DECLARE @field INT;
DECLARE @maxfield INT;
DECLARE @char INT;
DECLARE @fieldname VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @PKCols VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21);
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @Type CHAR(1);
DECLARE @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @OI VARCHAR(50)= '''';

/*now set some of these variables*/
SET @TableName = (
    SELECT 
        OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE 
        sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
);
SET @UserName = SYSTEM_USER;
SET @UpdateDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126);


INSERT INTO audit_trigger (    
                Type, 
                TableName, 
                PK, 
                FieldName, 
                OldValue, 
                NewValue, 
                UpdateDate, 
                UserName
            ) values ( @OI, @OI,@OI,@OI,@OI,@OI, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126) ,@OI   );

            
/*Action*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
         SET @Type = ''U''
    ELSE SET @Type = ''I''
    ELSE SET @Type = ''D'';

/*get list of columns*/
SELECT * 
INTO #ins
FROM INSERTED;

SELECT * 
INTO #del
FROM DELETED;


SELECT @PKCols = 
        COALESCE(@PKCols + '' and'', '' on'') 
        + '' i.['' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''] = d.['' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '']''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS pk
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS c ON (
            c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
            AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        )
    WHERE pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY'';

dificults starts above in concatening....................................................................................



                    END
                '
    FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND TABLE_NAME <> 'audit_trigger'
    ORDER BY    TABLE_NAME

OPEN cur_trigger

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_trigger INTO @SQL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_trigger INTO @SQL   
END

CLOSE cur_trigger
DEALLOCATE cur_trigger
```

i tried to put the script 1 into script 2 but happens so much concatening erros

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Maybe you could explore temporal tables introduced with SQL Server 2016? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: There are many issues going on here. For starters those catalog views are not very good. They are left there for backwards compatibility. You are using them to get the schema, but the documentation states you should not use these to find the schema of anything. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This entire approach is going to be filled with constant maintenance struggles. You will have to run something to create triggers on every new table you add to the system. The performance of your system is going to slow down noticeably when you start adding triggers (even worse with those loops inside) to every single DML operation. You are using strings as dates, not really sure why.

Comment: yes, i know about the performance is going to slow down. This script is on the localhost, not in the production release database and its only for identify system changes for study how code access db.